# Regex negated character class followed by optional character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to match two separate patterns. I can get the first working but not the second.

The first is that one of `[eE]` must be immediately preceded by one of `[cfd]` but one or more of `G` is optionally allowed between them. For example, the expression `[cfd]G*[eE]` works on this text as I would expect:
`cexmxcGexcexGGG0cexG0G00cGEgx0xgcex0xcGGGGEgx0xgmcexc`

The second pattern I want to match is any occurrence of `[eE]` preceded by `[^cfd]` even if there are zero, one or more of `G` between them. I think something like `[^cfd]G*[eE]` should work on a slightly modified text:
`cexmxcGexcexGGG0vexG0G00cGEgx0xgcex0xvGGGGEgx0xgmcexc`. I would only expect the `ve` and `vGGGGE` strings to be matched. However, I am getting the two other `G[eE]` patterns matched as well even though they are part of a valid `cG*e` matched by the first pattern `[cfd]G*[eE]`.

How do I avoid matching the `G[eE]` substrings in the second example and why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to match `ve` and `vGGGGE` you can exclude matching `G` om the negated character class as well.

What happens is that `[^cfd]` can also match a `G` char.

So `[^cfd]G*[eE]` can match G, then `G*` match optional G chars, and then matches `e` or `E` which can also match `Ge` and `GE`

```
[^cfdG]G*[eE]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t5Bd4g/1)

Comment: Neat, thank you. I had myself convinced it was more complicated than that!

Comment: Liam, though less desirable, `[^cfd](?<!G)G*[eE]` also works, provided the regex engine supports *negative lookbehinds* (here `(?<!G)`).

Comment: Interesting. This is what I was wondering (negative look behind) but didn't know how to construct it. I kind of prefer it because it doesn't "break" my prefix pattern which is either `[cfd]` or `[^cfd]`. Do you say it is less desirable because it is more complex or is there another reason?

Comment: @LiamCaffrey As you are already matching any character except `c` `f` `d` with the negated character class, the `(?<!G)` is an unnecessary extra assertion in `[^cfd](?<!G)G*[eE]` as this part `[^cfdG]G*[eE]` already rules out matching a `G` char.